# CUDA thrust: how to realize "partition" that supports "stencil"?

Tags: cuda, thrust

Suppose there is an array of intergers:

```
A[]={2, 2, 9, 8, 5, 7, 0, 6}
```

and a stencil:

```
B[]={1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
```

My question is how could we rearrange A[] according to B[] such that if B[i]==1, B[j]==0, then A[i] will be guaranteed to precede A[j] in the new array, which should look like:

```
C[]={2, 8, 5, 7, 6, 2, 9, 0}
```

PS: I found the ["partition"](http://thrust.github.com/doc/group__partitioning.html) function was almost the answer except that it only supported predicate. Is there any workaround?

Any hint is much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this just a stable sort by key?

Comment: That was not so obvious to me at the beginning. Thanks a lot, @talonmies !

Comment: Looks like `partition`-with-stencil is a known hole in the API: https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented using [`thrust::stable_sort_by_key()`](http://thrust.github.com/doc/group__sorting.html).

Answer (score 1):

Now that `thrust::partition` and `thrust::stable_partition` with stencil have been implemented (one may need to get the source from the [official Thrust repository](https://github.com/thrust/thrust)), this can be achieved with:

```
#include <thrust/partition.h>

struct is_one
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const int &x)
  {
    return x == 1;
  }
};

// Partition values on device thanks to stencil
thrust::stable_partition(d_A.begin(),
                         d_A.end(),
                         d_B.begin(),
                         is_one());
```

Which leads to:

```
    A =   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
    B =   0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
    C =   1  2  5  8  0  3  4  6  7  9
```

This implementation is more efficient since we are not sorting the values in the two partitions. A similar and more complex example is available [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16602201/1043187) (with some more details in the answer).